# Altering Excel Column Contents w/ Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having issues regarding manipulation of columns from excel, to excel. The first half of my code works when deleting columns in the xlsx file, but when converting it to a dataframe to alter the contents of the columns themselves it does not change the values of any of the columns. Where am I going wrong here?

```
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

#Pull todays date
now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%m%d%Y")

#Open correct workbook and sheet
wb = load_workbook("Output" + date_time + ".xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
sheetname ="Sheet1"

#Deleting useless columns to close down on file size
sheet.delete_cols(19, 3)
sheet.delete_cols(13, 5)
sheet.delete_cols(7, 1)
sheet.delete_cols(4, 1)
sheet.delete_cols(1, 2)

#Save workbook
wb.save("Output" + date_time + ".xlsx")

#Remove M from Store #
dfO = pd.read_excel('Output' + date_time + '.xlsx')
dfO["Store #"].str.replace("M","")

#Change time/date format
dfO['EstimatedDateStartUTC'] = pd.to_datetime(dfO.EstimatedDateStartUTC)

#dfO.drop(1, axis=1) #Numbered rows column

#Save workbook
dfO.to_excel("Output" + date_time + ".xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have the answer -

When trying to reference dataframe columns and update them, they do not just automatically update in the DF, they need to be updated manually. Here's the correction code. Hopefully this helps someone!

```
#Remove M from Store #
dfO = pd.read_excel('Output' + date_time + '.xlsx')
dfOS = dfO['Store #'].str.removeprefix("M")
dfO.update(dfOS, overwrite=True)

#Change time/date format
dfOT = dfO['EstimatedDateStartUTC'].dt.date
dfO.update(dfOT, overwrite=True)
```